# Updateing image field fails for any user except super user in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, imagefield

I installed ImageField and used it to create News widget , SlideShow widget and ...
When I try to change the picture and publish changes for any item containing ImageField , if the super user is logged in, all changes saves successfully.

But if any other user with any role is logged in then the changed picture name does not save in database but all other field like text and date and ... stores successfully.

Thank you in advance for your help...!

Comment: What ImageField? The obsolete one? Which Orchard version? Checked the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the following link , **Sebastien Ros** , the creator of ImageField for orchard answered my question.

https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/569286

**"Don't use the ImageField, it has been deprectaed in favor of the MEdiaPickerField."**

So I used MediaPickerField and MediaGalleryField instead.

Thanks for your attentions...

BR :) ...